# Refreshing Javascript on the page without refreshing HTML

Tags: javascript, html, mathjax

A little context on my problem.
I am updating the MathML in this div that is currently displaying HTML. When I load the page the first time, if runs the MathJax script and displays all the MathML perfectly.
When I click "Preview Changes", a button that takes the current changes made in a text area and displays them on the preview div, the MathML disappears.

I think problem here is that refreshing the div doesn't trigger the MathJax script. I have tried $.getScript(), and I tried adding a script using document.createElement(script) everytime the preview changes button is clicked, but all that to no avail.

I was hoping if someone could help me w/ this.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It sounds like you will need to reinitialize MathJax upon refreshing your ajax result. Can you provide some code you've tried so far?

Comment: Also, I'm not using AJAX. I just do a `$(DivIDHere).html(htmlToReplaceHere)`

Comment: Ah, my mistake. If possible, I'd like to see your HTML to clarify how MathJax interacts with it. Does MathJax simply return a value which you then insert into your div? If you are simply replacing HTML content in `DivIDHere`, there's no reason you can't replace it again and again. If you destroy the div you are selecting, that would be a problem.

Comment: This is the HTML
`<div id="preview"></div>`
And this is the Javascript that updates the HTML
`$('#preview').html($('#hdnPreviewHTML').val());`
All MathJax is doing is converting all the `<math>...</math>` tags in the HTML to MathML.

Comment: `var script = document.createElement("script"); script.type = "text/javascript"; script.src = "Scripts/MathJax/v2.1/Ma‌​thJax.js?config=TeX-AMS-MML_HTMLorMML"; document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);` I tried it this way, and that is not work.

Comment: What are the contents of `#hdnPreviewHTML`? `val()` is primarily used to get values from form elements. You may want to try `$('#preview').html($('#hdnPreviewHTML').html());`.

Comment: The answer down there worked, but your help is much appreciated. :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MathJax.Hub.Typeset()` is the JavaScript command that can re-render the math content within your page or within individual elements that have been updated by current changes. If you are sure that all typesetting is finished, then you can call it directly, but in general it is good to use the safe way to call it, like this `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);`

Read more instructions for how to use it here: http://docs.mathjax.org/en/v1.1-latest/typeset.html

For instance, `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,"previewdiv"]);` would re-render the updated contents of the HTML element with an ID of `previewdiv` after you have updated its contents using your jQuery call.

Comment: AWESOME! Thanks, that worked. Here is the code I used.
`var divML = document.getElementById("preview");
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub,divML]);`
Thanks again!!