# MathJax not rendering latex

Tags: javascript, mathjax

I've tryed to embed MathJax into a page to have latex rendered as real formula/expressions however I get no errors nor any rendering. The code is taken directly from the MathJax documentation

I have the following code

```
var div = MathJax.HTML.Element(
  "div",
  {id: "MathDiv", style:{border:"1px solid", padding:"5px"}},
  ["Here is math: \\(x+1\\)",["br"],"and a display $$x+1\\over x-1$$"]
);
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

that executes with no errors, so MathJax is loaded correctly and there's no errors in the console either. So very little information to go on. Any good suggestion to how I debug this scenario or even better a solution :)

Comment: Have you seen [this part of the docs](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/typeset.html)?

Comment: @PeterKrautzberger if you write that up as a propper answer I'll up vote it

Comment: Well, technically this is a duplicate (though  there are many) of e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/17054116/1339651

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

<!-- or use the cdn for mathjax source code -->
<script src="../MathJax/MathJax.js">
  MathJax.Hub.Config({
    jax: ["input/TeX","output/HTML-CSS"],
    extensions: ["tex2jax.js"],
    tex2jax: {
      inlineMath: [ ['\\(','\\)'] ],
      displayMath: [ ['$$','$$'] ]
    }
  });

  function doOnLoad() {
    var div = MathJax.HTML.Element(
          "div",
          {id: "MathDiv", style:{border:"1px solid", padding:"5px"}},
          ["Here is math: \\(x^2+1\\)",["br"],"and a display $$x+1\\over x-1$$"]
        );
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    // This does not seem needed but you can use if to force rendering of a div
    // MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub,'MathDiv']);
  }
</script>

</head>
<body onload="doOnLoad();">

</body>
</html>
```

I think you need to add the div in the onload method, so the div is added after the page has been fully parsed.