# HTML MathJax Preview Adding text

Tags: javascript, text, mathjax

I have an input which gets some TeX text to give it to my script element which shows preview of it. But I cant add this text to it properly to display preview. What do I need to do? P.S I`m Using MathJax.

```
<script type="math/tex" id ="MathJax-Element-1"></script>
<input type="text" id="testbox" onkeyup="change1()" onchange = "change1()"onfocus="change1()" onblur="change1()" ></input>
<script type="text/javascript">
function change1(){
$('#MathJax-Element-1').text($('#testbox').attr('value').toString());
}
</script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Refreshing Javascript on the page without refreshing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17053226/refreshing-javascript-on-the-page-without-refreshing-html)

Comment: You should consider using the MathJax API to make these changes, rather than manipulating the page yourself.  You should not be modifying the MathJax script element by hand.  See [this page](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/typeset.html#manipulating-individual-math-elements) for a description of how to obtain the MathJax "element jax" for the math expression and change its content.